# Allow access to tablet data security dialog box

Tags: security, usb

I have been given the task to get some android tablets (SM-T500) working in kiosk mode (soti mobicontrol). The issue is when they are in kiosk mode it blocks the USB switcher menu and the allow access to tablet data dialog box

I have managed to get the USB switcher menu working by allowing **Launch://com.android.settings/.Settings$UsbDetailsActivity** to launch but for the life of me I cannot workout what apk strand (not sure if thats the correct terminology) that controls the "Allow access to tablet data" security dialog box

I am new to android and usually only work with ios.... would anybody be able to point me in the right direction??

Comment: Usually in the debug settings menu you can set a default USB mode. If you set this to USB file transfer then you don't have to care about the dialog.

Comment: Hey Robert, this is true - i have it set as transferring files at default, so i could probably get rid of the Launch://com.android.settings/.Settings$UsbDetailsActivity
As the tablets are locked down in kiosk mode they still need the "allow access to tablet data" dialog box whitelisted but i can't find that dialog in the com.android.settings apk. I'm not sure where to look next.....

Answer (score 0):

Working with Soti we have found the activity that runs this popup message is com.samsung.android.MtpApplication/.USBConnection - allowing this to the whitelist allowed it through the kiosk mode (just in case anyone falls into the same black hole i did)